# Aligning CSS spans correctly

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I have a very simple-looking problem in my web page.

First, here are my HTML and CSS snippets:

```css
.middle-side p span.two {
 margin: 0 0em 0 1em;
}
.middle-side p span.bath8 {
  margin: 0 56% 0 0;
}
.middle-side p span.bath7 {
  margin: 0 46% 0 0;
}
.middle-side p span.bath6 {
  margin: 0 36% 0 0;
}
.middle-side p span.bath5 {
  margin: 0 37% 0 0;
}
.middle-side p span.bath3 {
  margin: 0 24% 0 0;
}
.middle-side p span.bath2 {
  margin: 0 14% 0 0;
}
.middle-side p span.bath1 {
  margin: 0 32% 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 middle-side immediate">
   <h4>Features:</h4>

   <p><span class="bath1">Floor</span>:<span class="two"> {{listing.floor}}</span></p>

   <p><span class="bath2">Price</span>:<span class="two"> {{listing.price}}</span></p>

   <p><span class="bath3">Plot Area</span>:<span class="two"> {{listing.size}}</span></p>

   <p><span class="bath4">Number of rooms</span>:<span class="two"> {{listing.rooms}}</span></p>

   <p><span class="bath5">Elevator</span>:<span class="two"> {{listing.elevator}}</span></p>

   <p><span class="bath6">Air Conditioned</span>:<span class="two"> {{listing.airConditioning}}</span></p>

   <p><span class="bath7">Renovated</span>:<span class="two"> {{listing.renovated}}</span></p>

   <p><span class="bath8">Balcony</span>:<span class="two"> {{listing.price}}</span></p>
</div>
```

This yields:

[image: wrong]

And I want it to be aligned correctly, like this:

[image: correct]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: ,I would use a table to achieve this instead of spans.

Comment: check my example before. Using a table I think is always a better approach than spans. IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a width for first span child of "immediate" class like this:

```
.immediate p span:first-child{
  display:inline-block;
  width:35%;
}
```

[This is the example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4qzdgeuv/2/)

Comment: Add more width. I have set this to 35% but this value you must change for your element and font size.

Comment: Thanks alot! Your solution saved me and was the easiest to implement. Obviously I accepted your answer and voted up :)

Comment: @Idos Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

The code would look something like this. Adapt it to your needing:

```
<div class="box1">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0"onMouseover="changeto(event, '#D0DFEC')" onMouseout="changeback(event, '#ffffff')"width="100%">
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;">
            <td><strong>Floor:</strong></td>
            <td><font color="0075DB">5th</font></td>

        </tr>
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;">
            <td><strong>Price:</strong></td>
            <td><font color="0075DB">150,000€</font></td>

        </tr>
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;">
            <td><strong>Plot Area:</strong></td>
            <td><font color="0075DB">Madrid, Spain</font></td>

        </tr>
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;">
            <td><strong>Number of rooms:</strong></td>
            <td><font color="0075DB">7</font></td>

        </tr>
        <tr  style="border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;">
            <td><strong>Elevator:</strong></td>
            <td><font color="0075DB">Yes</font></td>

        </tr>
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;">
            <td><strong>Air Conditioned:</strong></td>
            <td><font color="0075DB">No</font></td>

        </tr>
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;">
            <td><strong>Renovated:</strong></td>
            <td><font color="0075DB">Yes</font></td>

        </tr>
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;">
            <td><strong>Balcony:</strong></td>
            <td><font color="0075DB">Yes</font></td>

        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

I added some mouse click event to make it look fancier, also make sure that if you use bootstrap, you do meet all bootstrap requirements regarding columns.(encapsulate the div that contains the column in a row etc etc)

[This is the example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hv684t8/)

Edit: Though the other solution is correct, I´d always use a table for such this thing

Comment: Correct your code. The font tag must be closed before the end of TD tag :)

Comment: @Baro, yeah you´re right. My fault. Good code is always better :)

Comment: Not to nitpick, but actually [`<font>` is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font).

Comment: @iamnotmaynard, I know, but I wanted to avoid using CSS.

Comment: You could use the `style` attribute on the `td` elements themselves.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard, Yeah, you can do `style="color:#0075DB:"` but I took this code from and old proyect and I did not change it. Also I think it´s gonna be useless to this guys so he´ll take rid of it. But yeah it´s not good using obsolete things because google may penalize you. Inline CSS will do the job :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this...

```
.middle-side p span:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}

.middle-side p span.two {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonathanzuniga/y3xcg646/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the structure you have, the correct approach would be to use the various table model values of the [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property. To treat `div.middle-side` as the table, the `p` elements as rows, and the `span` elements inside them as cells, you would do something like:

```
.middle-side {
     display: table;
}
.middle-side p {
    display: table-row;
}
.middle-side p span {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5oLvh786/).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using [**flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

**HTML**

Just wrap the colon in a `span`, so it's not an [anonymous element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous), which means it wouldn't be styleable or selectable.

**CSS**

Replace your code with this:

```
.col-sm-4 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.col-sm-4 > p {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.col-sm-4 > p > span:nth-child(1) {
    flex: 0 0 20%;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.col-sm-4 > p > span:nth-child(2) {
    flex: none;
    background-color: pink;
}

.col-sm-4 > p > span:nth-child(3) {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

The code above results in this responsive layout:

[image]

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/hgxw1ze4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css framework you are using to achieve this:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

.two span{
    padding-right:5px;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 middle-side immediate">
    <h4>Features:</h4>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="bath1 col-sm-6">Floor</div>
        <div class="two col-sm-6"> 
        <span>:</span> 
            {{listing.floor}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="bath2 col-sm-6">Price</div>
        <div class="two col-sm-6"> 
        <span>:</span> 
            {{listing.price}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="bath3 col-sm-6">Plot Area</div>
        <div class="two col-sm-6"> 
        <span>:</span> 
            {{listing.size}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="bath4 col-sm-6">Number of rooms</div>
        <div class="two col-sm-6"> 
        <span>:</span> 
            {{listing.rooms}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="bath5 col-sm-6">Elevator</div>
        <div class="two col-sm-6"> 
        <span>:</span> 
            {{listing.elevator}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="bath6 col-sm-6">Air Conditioned</div>
        <div class="two col-sm-6"> 
        <span>:</span> 
            {{listing.airConditioning}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="bath7 col-sm-6">Renovated</div>
        <div class="two col-sm-6"> 
        <span>:</span> 
            {{listing.renovated}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="bath8 col-sm-6">Balcony</div>
        <div class="two col-sm-6"> 
        <span>:</span> 
            {{listing.price}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
</div>
```

This will save a lot of time. When going responsive.